# Цепочка ML models

Tags: искусственный-интеллект

Есть ли примеры проектов, где используется не одна обученная модель, а целая цепочка. Или еще более сложная архитектура, составленная из отдельных моделей, действующих как единое целое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то есть. Называется это Stacking. Но если вас интересует вопрос усиления, например, предсказательной способности алгоритмов машинного обучения, то кроме стэкинга надо не забыть посмотреть на то, что называется Ensemble Learning. И то и другое, как раз и есть "сложная архитектура, составленная из отдельных моделей, действующих как единое целое" но составленные исходя их разных парадигм.

Для начала взгляните, например, на обсуждение вот тут:

https://www.quora.com/What-is-stacking-in-machine-learning
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stacking-in-machine-learning/
http://blog.kaggle.com/2016/12/27/a-kagglers-guide-to-model-stacking-in-practice/
https://machinelearningmastery.com/stacking-ensemble-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/

а про "ансамблирование" -  вот тут

https://blog.statsbot.co/ensemble-learning-d1dcd548e936

И их сравнение -

https://medium.com/@rrfd/boosting-bagging-and-stacking-ensemble-methods-with-sklearn-and-mlens-a455c0c982de